# CSS causing problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, spacing

I bought a wordpress theme. I have installed it and have done everything. The problem is that some CSS is creating problem in the spacing of the content.

See this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTUAO.jpg The content should be inside the "yellow box" but the content is going till the "red box"(see image). The URL of the site is discountcouponsforflipkart.com and you may go there and see the website yourself. I have wasted my whole day for it but still I can't figure it out. I request you to please go to the site and check the CSS via firebug plugin for firefox(I guess every coder should have it) and tell me the thing that is creating this problem! If you want then I can post it here but the CSS is really long! Thanks if someone could help me.

The CSS is over here http://pastebin.com/TLqvUWKb

Comment: posting the css and html here is a lot easier for coders than guessing or saying that everyone should have firebug.. posting code will get you much more help and probably a lot less minus votes

Comment: Bit of a vague title for a question.. People in their right minds would also not click links to your website, especially considering you are a new user. Could be spyware for all we know...

Comment: It is very evident that you did not [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: Ok I will post the CSS here.

Comment: I think you should ask for support to the developer who made the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to say you haven't looked at the elements separately.

```
#container1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -140px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Have a look at height, I changed it too auto instead of a fixed height.

Comment: ok, I tried and now all the content is within the box, but I actually wanted that the content should be closer to each other rather than being far away! any solution to it?

Comment: In your CSS look for all of the elements which are being used and changed the padding and margin. I would suggest creating a backup first. You can change the padding and margin inside the wordpress admin. Via Appearance > Edit > Stylesheet.css

Comment: I have uploaded the CSS over here, please have a look at it and let me know what to change. http://pastebin.com/TLqvUWKb Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've given you the resources to do it yourself... You paid for the theme, ask the theme developer or contact someone and pay them to do it.